# Tensor $\mathbb{Z}^n$ with $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, tensor-products

> It is true that $\mathbb{R}^n\simeq\mathbb{Z}^n\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R}$?

If true what would be the isomorphism?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Note that $f:\mathbb Z^n\otimes_{\mathbb Z} \mathbb R\to \mathbb R^n$ is a vector space over $\mathbb R$ with basis
$$(1,0,0,\ldots,0)\otimes 1,(0,1,0,\ldots,0)\otimes 1,\ldots,(0,0,0,\ldots,1)\otimes 1$$
so we can define an isomorphism by sending the $i$th element of this basis to $e_i\in\mathbb R^n$.

Comment: @user137679 No problem. If this answers your question, you can click the green check mark to the left of the answer. That marks the question as "answered", and rewards me with 15 reputation. :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes because $$\mathbb{Z}^{n}\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R} \cong (\bigoplus_{1}^{n}\mathbb{Z} )\otimes_{\mathbb{Z}} \cong  \bigoplus_{1}^{n}(\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R})$$ but $\mathbb{R}$ is a $\mathbb{Z}$- module , so $\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R} \cong \mathbb{R}$ and then $$\bigoplus_{1}^{n}(\mathbb{Z} \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}}\mathbb{R}) \cong \bigoplus_{1}^{n}\mathbb{R} = \mathbb{R}^{n}$$